# Mongodb - how to add a field from a one-to-one relationship to a nested object

Tags: mongodb

I would like to add a field **length** in each **data_set** object of **contributors** from another collection **files**
The relation between a dataset and a file is one-to-one.

contributors Collection

```
[{
    "_id": "123456",
    "data_sources": [{
            "id": "a0d20c86-a178-4bdc-8448-ec8ea1748e04",
            "name": "contributor1",
            "data_sets": [{
                "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:20:30.791798+00:00",
                "id": ObjectId("5d08acde2b33b0f9082ff7d2")
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "contributor2",
            "id": "3928e378-a400-44e9-a88c-62b544c970cd",
            "data_sets": [{
                    "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:20:35.071041+00:00",
                    "id": ObjectId("5d08ace2ac1be4eeab4be6da")
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:46:56.623600+00:00",
                    "id": ObjectId("5d08b31059ccc2e56d4be6da")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

files collection

```
[
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08acde2b33b0f9082ff7d2"),
    "length" : 765,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08ace2ac1be4eeab4be6da"),
    "length" : 6952,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d08b31059ccc2e56d4be6da"),
    "length" : 145,
}
]
```

Expected result

```
[{
    "_id": "123456",
    "data_sources": [{
            "id": "a0d20c86-a178-4bdc-8448-ec8ea1748e04",
            "name": "contributor1",
            "data_sets": [{
                "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:20:30.791798+00:00",
                "id": ObjectId("5d08acde2b33b0f9082ff7d2"),
                "length": 765
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "contributor2",
            "id": "3928e378-a400-44e9-a88c-62b544c970cd",
            "data_sets": [{
                    "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:20:35.071041+00:00",
                    "id": ObjectId("5d08ace2ac1be4eeab4be6da"),
                    "length": 6952
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-06-18T09:46:56.623600+00:00",
                    "id": ObjectId("5d08b31059ccc2e56d4be6da"),
                    "length": 145
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What I've tried

```
db.getCollection('contributors').aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$data_sources'},
    {$unwind: '$data_sources.data_sets'},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "fs.files",
            localField: "data_sources.data_sets.id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "files"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "data_sources.data_sets.size": {"$arrayElemAt":["$files.length",0]}
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
           "data_sources": { $push: "$data_sources"},

        }
    },
])
```

I can't get back to the original structure and I don't know if it's possible.

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Would looping all docs in files and then update the contributors with individual updates be acceptable?

Comment: it would be possible but I wonder if I could do it with only one query